# Laravel 5 create pagination from json data in blade view

Tags: json, laravel-5, pagination

I have done the query below, and I am able to get the json data from console log, my question is how to make a pagination link using the json data?

```
$viewData = DB::table('tbl_contents')
                ->where('record_type', '=', 'Event')
                ->where('status', '=', 1)
                ->paginate(3);

return json_encode($viewData);
```

Comment: What version of laravel are you using?

Comment: @user1191749 I am using 5.2 now.

Answer (score 0):

You may also return the pagination link, see my code below:

```
$viewData = DB::table('tbl_contents')
                ->where('record_type', '=', 'Event')
                ->where('status', '=', 1)
                ->paginate(3);

return [
    'items' => json_encode($viewData),
    'pagination_link' => $viewData->links()
];
```

Comment: What if I am using a custom pagination?

Comment: Kindly paste your full code in your question, how do you show the pagination data